# How to check that pointer is writing in the out of allocated memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I come across this question during discussion with interviewer:

If I have allocated 4 bytes of memory from malloc.

```
int *p = (int*) malloc(4);
```

now if I moved pointer by 4 byte.

```
p++;
```

And now pointer is pointing memory which is out of 4 byte of memory allocated by malloc. Let's assume that this memory has permission to read-write.

```
*p=4;
```

That means pointer is going out of allocated memory.

Now consider a case where I allocated some memory but whenever my pointer moves out of allocated and write on that memory then I want to be informed but how??

I have only malloc and free to use.

Comment: C does not have automatic bounds checking. You'll have to keep track of the size of your allocations manually.

Comment: unclear. Why don't use a tool to get the job done?

Comment: You should point out to your interviewer that `int *p = (int *)malloc(4);` is very poorly written C code.  You should always avoid casting the return of malloc in C.`  This also assumes that `int` is a 4 byte value on some arbitrary platform which might be common but certainly is not safe.

Comment: You should also avoid altering `p` since you won't be able to `free` the memory - assign `p` to another variable and increment that one, or index `p`.

Comment: In the case you've provided, the read and write are definitely undefined behavior but are quite likely "safe" since it is rare that an underlying memory allocation routine will give you only 4 bytes in a chunk.  However, if you'd like to be warned, you need to a) use something other than C, b) use a memory management library that (has lots of overhead and) detects out of bounds memory read/writes, c) use a dynamic code analysis tool like Valgrind or Coverity.

Comment: @SouravGhosh is there any tool to find Out of Bound Memory Address condition? When i tested it with Keil MDK IDE, with C99 compiler it do not showing any warning about this problem.

Comment: @Salman In general, valgrind is a very good tool, but i'm not very sure if that suits your need.

Answer (score 2):

There's a library called *[Electric Fence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence)* that does what you want.

It intercepts your malloc calls. It works by allocating pages of memory and placing the page boundary exactly at the end of your allocated memory. The page after the allocated
memory is unmapped. If the program tries to write past the allocated memory, a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) is generated.

Answer (score 1):

C does not feature what you request nativly, and compilers will in general not detect out of bound arrays on non-static variables.

In runtime, these can be detected if using tools like valgrind and libefence. These tools however are only meant for debugging and not release, since they increase the memory pressure, CPU-usage and context switches.

At compile time, there exists analyzing tools (static analysis) that simulates what the program does, and try to detect misbehavior like these.

What you can do is to make your own data structure that contains the length information and such, and have your own read/write functions that uses this structure. This is the typical approach that high-level languages like PHP and python do internally.